# How to upload an .lrc file in Codelgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, .lrc

I want to upload an `.lrc` file in Codelgniter

But it always says:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

I tried adding:

```
'lrc'   =>  'application/octet-stream'
```

in **MIMES.php**, but it still doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look at the content and you could try a text based or application based

`'lrc' => 'text/plain';`

`'lrc'  =>  array('application/XXyourapplicationXX', 'application/XX YourApplicationXX')`